# Error message when importing .csv files into MySQL using Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am a novice when it comes to Python and I am trying to import a .csv file into an already existing MySQL table. I have tried it several different ways but I cannot get anything to work. Below is my latest attempt (not the best syntax I'm sure). I originally tried using ‘%s’ instead of ‘?’, but that did not work. Then I saw an example of the question mark but that clearly isn’t working either. What am I doing wrong?

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

db = mysql.connector.connect(**Login Info**)

mycursor = db.cursor()
df = pd.read_csv("CSV_Test_5.csv")

insert_data = (
    "INSERT INTO company_calculations.bs_import_test(ticker, date_updated, bs_section, yr_0, yr_1, yr_2, yr_3, yr_4, yr_5, yr_6, yr_7, yr_8, yr_9, yr_10, yr_11, yr_12, yr_13, yr_14, yr_15)"
    "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    )

for row in df.itertuples():
    data_inputs = (row.ticker, row.date_updated, row.bs_section, row.yr_0, row.yr_1, row.yr_2, row.yr_3, row.yr_4, row.yr_5, row.yr_6, row.yr_7, row.yr_8, row.yr_9, row.yr_10, row.yr_11, row.yr_12, row.yr_13, row.yr_14, row.yr_15) 
    mycursor.execute(insert_data, data_inputs)

db.commit()
```

Error Message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\...\Python_Test\Excel_Test_v1.py",
> line 33, in <module>
>     mycursor.execute(insert_data, data_inputs)   File "C:\...\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py",
> line 325, in execute
>     raise ProgrammingError( mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: I'm not up on Python, but the syntax you've used when you're assigning a value to  `insert_data` doesn't look to me like it will create a single string. Can't you just assign a single string?

Comment: Try using `%s` instead of `?` for the parameter passing/formatting? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: I originally tried the solution in the documentation that recommended using ‘%s’ but I could not get it to work. Then I saw an example with a ‘?’ so I figured I would try it but failed miserably.

Comment: @Part_Time_Nerd When you say "failed miserably" do you mean you got the same error or did you get some other error?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Connector/Python supports named parameters (which includes also printf style parameters (format)).

```
>>> import mysql.connector
>>> mysql.connector.paramstyle
'pyformat'
```

According to [PEP-249](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/) (DB API level 2.0) the definition of pyformat is:

***pyformat: Python extended format codes, e.g. ...WHERE name=%(name)s***

Example:

```
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT %s", ("foo", ))
>>> cursor.fetchall()
[('foo',)]
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT %(var)s", {"var" : "foo"})
>>> cursor.fetchall()
[('foo',)]
```

Afaik the qmark paramstyle (using question mark as a place holder) is only supported by MariaDB Connector/Python.